# Display message on screen on link click until redirect

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick, message

I have a normal link to download a document on its click. It takes a while for the download to happen. I want to add a message "please wait ..." during the time it takes for the request to finish and the download to start on the browser. 
Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

Create an element like `<span id="statusmsg"></span>`
Add the `onclick` attribute to the `<a href` code.

With `jQuery`:

```
<a href="file_to_download.pdf" onClick="$('#statusmsg').text('Please wait..')">Download file</a>
```

Without `jQuery`

```
<a href="file_to_download.pdf" onClick="document.getElementById('statusmsg').innerHTML = 'Please wait..';">Download file</a>
```

See in action: https://jsfiddle.net/C0dekid/1uoe50a3/

Comment: How do I know that the file has downloaded though? At what point do you remove the message?

Comment: If you didn't put anything in the `<span id="statusmsg"></span>` the message should disappear by default after the page is loaded. I have made an example for you with loading time: http://system32.cf/test.php

Comment: the problem is, I am not redirecting to a page, I am simply downloading a document, so my page is not reloading.

Comment: Because the page isn't reloading, it's difficult to determine if the page is in load state or ready state. That's why the message is still there. To get rid of it you can redirect the users after 5 seconds for example to let them know the download is done. I made a new example for you: https://www.system32.cf/test.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $(this).append("<div class=loadingDiv>loading...</div>");
});
```

wanted to use fidle, but i'm still new to this stuff and can' ge it to work..